# Assembler char Output

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler

At the moment I'm working a bit with the Assembler language. I want to print a char to the console and my program runs without errors but it comes to no output. Here is my current code:

```
movl  $4, %eax         #Defines Output
movl  $1, %ebx         #STDOUT as first parameter
movl  $48, %ecx        #Copy char (0) to ECX
movl  $1, %edx         #String length 1
int   $0x80            #Trigger Interrupt

movl  %eax, %ebx       #Exitcode 0
movl  $1, %eax         #System Code SYS_EXIT
int   $0x80            #Trigger Interrupt
```

Do you have any ideas why it does not come to an output? As you can see I'm using the GAS syntax. What is the problem with my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `sys_write` call takes three parameters:

```
Register | Type         | Description
---------+--------------+----------------------------
ebx      | unsigned int | file descriptor
ecx      | const char * | pointer to data to write
edx      | size_t       | length of data
```

So your problem is that you're putting an *actual character* in `ecx`, where you should be putting a pointer to a string.

Comment: Okay thank you for this. If I push 48 to the stack I works great. So %ESP is a pointer to an adress or how can I imagine that?